# SSI includes not working on Debian with Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, server-side-includes

I'm trying to get SSI to work on Debian running Apache, however the `.shtml` files are not being parsed. From a PHP file with `phpinfo()` I can see that the following show up in the loaded modules section:

```
mod_mime_xattr mod_mime mod_mime_magic
```

In `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mime.conf` I have (among other things):

```
AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
```

In `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain.com.conf` (for the virtual host in question) I have:

```
<Directory /home/username/public_html>
Options +Includes
allow from all
AllowOverride All 
</Directory>
```

and for good measure, I added the following as well:

```
<Directory />
Options +Includes
</directory>
```

In the user's `.htaccess` file, I tried adding:

```
Options +Includes
AddType text/html shtml
AddHandler server-parsed shtml
```

Nothing seems to work. How can I even debug this?

Edit:

Here is the output of `ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/` in case this helps

```
actions.conf          dav_svn.load         proxy_balancer.load
actions.load          deflate.conf         proxy.conf
alias.conf            deflate.load         proxy_connect.load
alias.load            dir.conf             proxy_http.load
auth_basic.load       dir.load             proxy.load
auth_digest.load      env.load             python.load
authn_file.load       fcgid.conf           reqtimeout.conf
authz_default.load    fcgid.load           reqtimeout.load
authz_groupfile.load  mime.conf            rewrite.load
authz_host.load       mime.load            ruby.load
authz_user.load       mime_magic.conf      setenvif.conf
autoindex.conf        mime_magic.load      setenvif.load
autoindex.load        mime-xattr.load      ssl.conf
cgi.load              negotiation.conf     ssl.load
dav_fs.conf           negotiation.load     status.conf
dav_fs.load           php5.conf            status.load
dav.load              php5.load            suexec.load
dav_svn.conf          proxy_balancer.conf
```

Comment: When you visit a `.shtml` page do you see anything in the Apache error log?

Comment: Actually, yes. In error.log `[error] an unknown filter was not added: includes`

Comment: Commenting out the line `AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml` gets rid of the error, but still doesn't solve the problem

Comment: OK I figured it out. I'll post my answer in case others are having the same problems.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to get server side includes to work, the `include` module also needs to be loaded. You can do this by executing the following as root:

```
a2enmod include
```

Or execute the following:

```
ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/include.conf /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/include.conf
ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/include.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/include.load
```

Then restart apache.

Note, if you were adding SSI to `.shtml` files from `.htaccess` you would do `AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml`. Or substitute `.shtml` for whatever file type you want to be parsed by the server side includes.

The current Debian config file `/etc/apache2/mods-available/mime.conf` contains an error in that it adds the following:

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
[...]
AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
[...]
</IfModule>
```

without first checking whether `mod_include.c` has been loaded. To get around this, you can change those lines to:

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
[...]
<IfModule mod_include.c>
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>
[...]
</IfModule>
```

The `<IfModule>` tags can be nested. This will get rid of the error messages that you are experiencing in the event that `mod_include.c` is not loaded.